# i need help creating a stop watch for a reaction time tester

Tags: stopwatch

my problem is just creating a simple stop watch just need to stop and start on an event for the reaction time tester

I have tried creating one I was able to get one to work in seconds but I need one with milliseconds

I need a timer between when the user starts and stops it bye clicking again with needs to be in ms.

Comment: what is the tech stack that you want to use?

Comment: Im not sure what code.org uses or if it even it does use one , its a school project. I'm pretty new to coding